# Returning alphabet of any given language as array in PHP or Yii

Tags: php, yii, localization

Is it possible within Yii (or php even) given a language to get all the characters of that language's alphabet back? Pseudo code would be something like:

```
Yii::app()->language = 'en-US';
Yii::app()->returnAlphabetAsArray(); // returns ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ... 'Z']

Yii::app()->language = 'ru-RU';
Yii::app()->returnAlphabetAsArray(); // returns ['A', 'Б', 'В', 'Г' .... 'Я']
```

This needs to work for any given number of languages, so actually entering them into a database or array by hand for each language isn't really feasible. I've been surprised before by what is built into Yii so hopefully this is hidden somewhere.

Comment: Wait until you hit `'zh-CN'`...

Comment: Define the relationship between a "language" and "its alphabet" first. Is "ï" an "English letter"? No? But it's used in words like "naïve". Is "J" a "Japanese letter"? No? Then why is the country's rail system run by "JR"?

Comment: I'm assuming that relationship would already be tied to the language code I was using in Yii, the same way the dateformatter knows how to output the date based on the language.

Comment: The point is, what you're asking for is vaguely defined to begin with. How dates are formatted in a specific language/culture is pretty well defined. But which letters officially belong to a language is wide open to debate.

Comment: You could get the letters of *an alphabet*, like the Cyrillic alphabet. That's pretty well defined. But that alphabet is used in more than one language, and one language may use more than one alphabet in its written form (e.g. Japanese arguably uses Kanji, Katakana, Hiragana and the Latin alphabet).

Answer (score 0):

In pure PHP it's rather easy to get the English language letters in an array. Just use:

```
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
```

Unfortunately this won't work with other languages, so you can use something like this.

```
foreach(range(0x0391, 0x03A9) as $letter) {

    $alphabet[] = html_entity_decode("&#$letter;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
}
```

Here `0x0391` is the Hex for Greek letter Alpha (1st letter) and `0x03A9` is the Hex for Greek letter Omega (last letter). I know it's not 100% automated but it can save you some keystrokes as you have to define only the first and last chars of your languages and use a function that returns the whole character set.